# How to stream audio from PC to android device through USB?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop, usb, audio, streaming

[How to stream audio from PC to Android Device over Bluetooth](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19161/how-to-stream-audio-from-pc-to-android-device-over-bluetooth)

[Is there a way to stream all audio from PC to Android via USB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10350/is-there-a-way-to-stream-all-audio-from-pc-to-android-via-usb)

[Can I stream video from PC to an android device over USB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7034/can-i-stream-video-from-pc-to-an-android-device-over-usb)

I have found these questions, but since they're asked a few years ago, is it possible for now?

I've seen some new feature in android 5.0 and above, like this.
https://source.android.com/devices/audio/usb.html#androidSupport

But I don't know how to use those features to stream audio from pc to android device via USB, please help me!

Answer (score 1):

What you just read from the Android developer's guide is actually a specification for an Android device to send, not receive, audio using USB to an external device, such as a charging dock-cum-music player. This is a host mode USB connection. This does not allow your pc to send ( stream) audio to your device via USB. However, if your PC has Bluetooth, maybe you can register your phone as a Bluetooth audio player and stream audio to it that way.